# Python loop with enumerate by 2

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I'm not 100% sure how to pose the question's title, but what I want to do is simple. I want to loop over a list using the enumerate function in Python, but I want to know if it's possible to do it by 2, something I would do without enumerate, like this:

```
numbers = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five']

i = 0
for number in numbers:
    print(i, number)
    i += 2
```

Is it possible to do it using enumerate function (Pythonic way), or I should do it like in the example?

Comment: you could use `enumerate` and `print 2*i, number`

Comment: Your wording choice is a little unclear.  Do you want to iterate on the even numbered index items in the list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just *multiply* the `enumerate()` output by two:

```
for i, number in enumerate(numbers):
    print(i * 2, number)
```

This is essentially what the `range()` object does in Python 3; calculate the number for any given index. Since your series starts at 0, all you have to do is multiply `i` by your step size.

Another method would be to `zip()` a [`itertools.count()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) along:

```
from itertools import count
try:
    # Python 2, use the iterator version of zip
    from future_builtins import zip
except ImportError:
    # Python 3
    pass

for i, number in zip(count(step=2), numbers):
    print(i, number)
```

Demo in Python 3:

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> numbers = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five']
>>> for i, number in enumerate(numbers):
...     print(i * 2, number)
...
0 One
2 Two
4 Three
6 Four
8 Five
>>> for i, number in zip(count(step=2), numbers):
...     print(i, number)
...
0 One
2 Two
4 Three
6 Four
8 Five
```

Answer (score 2):

A little bit of profiling of Martijn's two Python 3 accepted solutions (tested on 3.7.4):

**enumerate()**:

```sh
python -m timeit -s "numbers = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five']" "for i, n in enumerate(numbers): i*2"
500000 loops, best of 5: 403 nsec per loop
```

**zip(count(...), ...)**:

```sh
python -m timeit -s "from itertools import count; numbers = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five']" "for i, n in zip(count(step=2), numbers): i"
500000 loops, best of 5: 690 nsec per loop
```

`zip`/`count` method is 1.7x slower.

**enumerate(...) & len(numbers) == 5000**:

```sh
python -m timeit -s "numbers = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five'] * 1000" "for i, n in enumerate(numbers): i*2"
1000 loops, best of 5: 324 usec per loop
```

**zip(count(...), ...) & len(numbers) == 5000**:

```sh
python -m timeit -s "from itertools import count; numbers = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five'] * 1000" "for i, n in zip(count(step=2), numbers): i"
1000 loops, best of 5: 219 usec per loop
```

With list length of 5000, `zip`/`count` method is a third faster, my guess is that the overhead of creating both the `zip` and `count` objects makes that method slower for small lists but that is eventually outweighed by having to perform `i * 2` so often in with a large number of iterations.

And of course, while the proportions look significant, in the first case we are talking a difference of `0.000000287` seconds, and in the large list case, `0.000105` seconds difference.